# Pagination PHP display negative numbers

Tags: php, pagination

I'm trying to code pagination and it should show this:

> <<1...11>>

but instead it shows this:

> <<-5...11>>

This happens if the content less than 11 pages.

this is my code

```
<?php if($page != 1): ?>

    <a href="?page=<?php echo $page-1; ?>&srch-term=<?php echo @$_GET['srch-term']; ?>&tag=<?php echo @$_GET['tag']; ?>&color=<?php echo @$_GET['color']; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
    </a>

<?php else: ?>

    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>

<?php endif; ?>

</li>

<?php
      $limitPage = 5;
      $fromPage = ($page - $limitPage) <= 0 ? 1:$page - $limitPage; 
      $endPage = ($page + $limitPage) >= $count? $count:$page+$limitPage;
      if($page <= ($limitPage)) $endPage = ($limitPage*2) + 1;
      if(($page - $limitPage) > ($count - ($limitPage*2))) $fromPage = $count - ($limitPage*2);
?>
<?php for($i=$fromPage;$i<=$endPage;$i++): ?>

    <li class="<?php echo ($page == $i)? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="?page=<?php echo $i; ?>&srch-term=<?php echo @$_GET['srch-term']; ?>&tag=<?php echo @$_GET['tag']; ?>&color=<?php echo @$_GET['color']; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>

<?php endfor; ?>

  <li class="<?php echo ($page == $count)? 'disabled':''; ?>">
        <?php if($page != $count): ?>
            <a href="?page=<?php echo $page+1; ?>&srch-term=<?php echo @$_GET['srch-term']; ?>&tag=<?php echo @$_GET['tag']; ?>&color=<?php echo @$_GET['color']; ?>" aria-label="Next">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: check this link : https://www.phpflow.com/php/simple-tutorial-of-pagination-in-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the line that is not working the way you expect.

```
 if(($page - $limitPage) > ($count - ($limitPage*2))) $fromPage = $count - ($limitPage*2);
```

Here is a php sandbox link with some debugging code that should help you out. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df2faac69d217ce8e5bea86b63325b8dd4c49600

```
$limitPage = 5;
$page = 1;
$count = 5;
$fromPage = ($page - $limitPage) <= 0 ? 1:$page - $limitPage; 
$endPage = ($page + $limitPage) >= $count? $count:$page+$limitPage;

echo $fromPage . ' ' . $endPage. "\n";

if($page <= ($limitPage)) $endPage = ($limitPage*2) + 1;

echo $fromPage . ' ' . $endPage. "\n";

if(($page - $limitPage) > ($count - ($limitPage*2))) $fromPage = $count - ($limitPage*2);

echo $fromPage . ' ' . $endPage;
```

Comment: Thank you.. it almost solve my problem.. i want to ask one question.. like how to limit the pagination based on the quantity of data/page. for example.. in my case one page there's 18 items of data. and let's say i have 19 items of data. so that 1 items should be on page 2 right? but in my case the paging display the page until page 11.  and i want to have the limit based on the data that i had (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I assume $page is the current page. What is $count and what is $limitPage?

Comment: so the $limitPage is for limit the display of the pagination. so if we don't include the $limitPage the pagination is going to display all the page that we had. so for example if we have 31 page and we exclude dt $limitPage in the code then it's gonna display from 1-31..

Comment: i have this value for $Count "$count = ceil(search_product_count($src,$tag,$color) / $limit);" and i think it's count the product when we are using search item

Comment: sorry.. i just got the wrong information.. so basically $limitPage=5 means that we had 5 page on counted from left and 5 page counted from right

Comment: so the total button should be 5+5+1